# Steam will not download

Tags: steam

This is the Error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6)
unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

Comment: I got the same error
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.